# Want to JOIN fourth table in query

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have four tables:

1. mls_category
2. points_matrix
3. mls_entry
4. bonus_points

My first table (mls_category) is like below:

```
*--------------------------------*
| cat_no |  store_id | cat_value |
*--------------------------------*
|   10   |    101    |     1     |
|   11   |    101    |     4     |
*--------------------------------*
```

My second table (points_matrix) is like below:

```
*----------------------------------------------------*
| pm_no |  store_id | value_per_point | maxpoint     |
*----------------------------------------------------*
|   1   |    101    |       1         |      10      |
|   2   |    101    |       2         |      50      |
|   3   |    101    |       3         |      80      |
*----------------------------------------------------*
```

My third table (mls_entry) is like below:

```
*-------------------------------------------*
| user_id |  category | distance |  status  |
*-------------------------------------------*
|    1    |     10    |    20    | approved |
|    1    |     10    |    30    | approved |
|    1    |     11    |    40    | approved |
*-------------------------------------------*
```

My fourth table (bonus_points) is like below:

```
*--------------------------------------------*
| user_id |  store_id | bonus_points | type  |
*--------------------------------------------*
|    1    |    101    |      200     | fixed |
|    2    |    102    |      300     | fixed |
|    1    |    103    |       4      |  per  |
*--------------------------------------------*
```

Now, I want to add bonus points value into the sum of total distance according to the store_id, user_id and type.

I am using the following code to get total distance:

```
SELECT MIN(b.value_per_point) * d.total_distance FROM points_matrix b 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT store_id, sum(t1.totald/c.cat_value) as total_distance FROM mls_category c 
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT SUM(distance) totald, user_id, category FROM mls_entry 
        WHERE user_id= 1 AND status = 'approved' GROUP BY user_id, category
    ) t1 ON c.cat_no = t1.category
) d ON b.store_id = d.store_id AND b.maxpoint >= d.total_distance
```

The above code is correct to calculate value, now I want to JOIN my fourth table.

This gives me sum (60*3 = 180) as total value. Now, I want (60+200)*3 = 780 for user 1 and store id 101 and value is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your query will be like below

```
SELECT Max(b.value_per_point)*( max(d.total_distance)+max(bonus_points)) FROM mls_point_matrix b
JOIN
(
   SELECT store_id, sum(t1.totald/c.cat_value) as total_distance FROM mls_category c
   JOIN
   (
       SELECT SUM(distance) totald, user_id, category FROM mls_entry
       WHERE user_id= 1 AND status = 'approved' GROUP BY user_id, category
   ) t1 ON c.cat_no = t1.category group by store_id
) d ON b.store_id = d.store_id inner join bonus_points bp on bp.store_id=d.store_id
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://rextester.com/OUTO98829)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but it is showing values. I just wanna bonus_points value into SUM(distance) as totald.

Comment: @zaynulAbdin now the error coming " Column 'store_id' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: @SantoshKhatri edited that was typo check please now

Comment: @zaynulAbdin One question how the query identify the store_id. means i have multiply store_id and i want 101 store_id data.

Comment: use where condition where c.store_id=101

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182790/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-santosh-khatri).